# Understanding the requirement for the related field to provide a queryset

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-serializer

Consider:

```
class CouponSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    courses = serializers.PrimaryKeyRelatedField(
        many=True, read_only=True)
    class Meta:
        model = Coupon
        exclude = ['users']
```

If I remove `read_only=True`, I get the error:

```
AssertionError: Relational field must provide a `queryset` argument, override `get_queryset`, or set read_only=`True`.
```

The [documentation](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/relations/#primarykeyrelatedfield) states:

> The queryset used for model instance lookups when validating the field input. Relationships must either set a queryset explicitly, or set read_only=True

What is the logic underlying this requirement? Why is there no such requirement for `StringRelatedField`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Django Rest Framework has to know which queryset to look in for if the number the user sends in the request is valid.

Let's say a user sends a POST request to your view that uses this serializer. With a payload like this:

```
{
   "courses": [1, 2, 3]
}
```

So, we want to create an instance of `Coupon` with the field `courses` to be populated with the instances of `Course` with id 1, 2 and 3.

DRF will validate this request to make sure that the primary keys 1, 2 and 3 exists in the model `Course`. If we don't add `queryset = Course.objects.all()` then DRF doesn't know which model to look in.

The reason you don't have to add to `StringRelatedField` is because that sort of field is read-only by default.

**Edit:**

If you use `read_only=True`, then DRF will check in the model on the same field name the you have defined on the serializer. In you example Serializer you have named the field `courses`, so DRF will check the model for a field named `courses` and it know's it's a many-to-many field so it will fetch all primary keys from that.

You might ask yourself why DRF don't do the same thing on write. That is use the field name from the serializer to find out what model the field is referring to in the model. I don't have a good answer for this however.

Comment: Oops, I had not noticed that the related field does not specify a model. Now I am really confused. Namely, consider a list view, where we only read, so that we can use `read_only=True`. How will the list view based on this serializer know which model to get the courses (either their PKs or string representations) from?

Comment: I added an edit with a follow-up answer to your question.

Answer (score 1):

you need to add ready_only if you just will use this serializer to view data or using  queryset argument  if you want to save data, this let the serializer validate data before saving it to the database

example

```
class CouponSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    courses = serializers.PrimaryKeyRelatedField(
        many=True, queryset = Course.objects.all() )
    class Meta:
        model = Coupon
        exclude = ['users']
```

this when validating data if not courses in your course list will raise error